# Dynamically convert row into columns based on the content in the cell in SQL Server & Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, plsql

Using procedure i am trying to achieve below use case. Can someone please guide me. 
Here is the data which is present in a table

```
Source Table : 

ID  | attendance |
------------------
123 | MTW
124 | TW
------------------

Target Table :

ID  | attendance
-----------------
123 | M
123 | T
123 | W
124 | T
124 | W
-----------------
```

Comment: You won't get one solution that fits both `[oracle]` and `[sql-server]`. This problem requires hierarchical processing. SQL solutions will use variant  syntax in the two DBMS flavours. For procedural solutions PL/SQL and T-SQL are completely different.

Answer (score 4):

Try this in Oracle.

```
select id, substr(attendance, level, 1) attendance
from   yourtable
connect by level <= LENGTH(attendance) and
prior id = id and
           prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9c2e/6)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `CONNECT BY` comparing the length of the varchar

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/306)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
select * from dual
```

**Query 1**:

```
with tab(id,att) as (
  select 123, 'MTW' from dual union
  select 124, 'TW' from dual
) select distinct id, substr(att, level-1, 1) a from tab t
connect by (level-1) <= LENGTH(att) 
order by id

**[Results][2]**:
    |  ID | A |
    |-----|---|
    | 123 | M |
    | 123 | T |
    | 123 | W |
    | 124 | T |
    | 124 | W |
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to achieve it using an Oracle Procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE src_test AS
SELECT 123 AS id, 'MTW' AS attendance FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 124 AS id, 'TW' AS attendance FROM dual;
/
Table SRC_TEST created.

CREATE TABLE tgt_test AS
SELECT * FROM src_test WHERE 1 = 2;
/
Table TGT_TEST created.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_src_to_test (
        p_errcode OUT VARCHAR2,
        p_errmsg OUT VARCHAR2 )
IS
    V_ITER NUMBER;
BEGIN
    p_errcode := 0;
    p_errmsg := 'TASK SUCCESSFUL' ;
    SELECT
        MAX ( LENGTH ( attendance ) )
    INTO
        V_ITER
    FROM
        src_test;
    FOR i IN 1 .. V_ITER
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO tgt_test
            ( id, attendance
            )
        SELECT
            id,
            SUBSTR ( attendance, i, 1 )
        FROM
            src_test
        WHERE 
            SUBSTR ( attendance, i, 1 ) IS NOT NULL;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    p_errcode := SQLCODE;
    p_errmsg := SUBSTR ( SQLERRM, 1, 200 ) ;
END pr_src_to_test;
/
Procedure PR_SRC_TO_TEST compiled

var p_errcode VARCHAR2(10);
var p_errmsg VARCHAR2(200);
EXEC pr_src_to_test (:p_errcode,:p_errmsg);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

print p_errcode;
P_ERRCODE
---------
0

print p_errmsg;
P_ERRMSG
--------
TASK SUCCESSFUL

select * from src_test order by 1;
        ID ATTENDANCE
---------- ----------
       123 MTW
       124 TW 

select * from tgt_test order by 1;
        ID ATTENDANCE
---------- ----------
       123 M  
       123 T  
       123 W  
       124 T  
       124 W  

drop procedure pr_src_to_test;
Procedure PR_SRC_TO_TEST dropped.

drop table src_test;
Table SRC_TEST dropped.

drop table tgt_test;
Table TGT_TEST dropped.
```